# How to get itemID from browser and echo to input?

Tags: php

I have got almost everything to work, but to get the itemid from the browser and echo to the input value.

This is my browser output:

```
localhost/webapp/admin.php?check=C7/itemid=143
```

And this is my input that isn't finding the itemID

```
<a>Enter Item ID 1:</a> 
<input type="number" name="itemID1" value="<?php echo $_GET['itemID']?>">
```

Comment: You are sure the link shouldn't be `localhost/webapp/admin.php?check=C7&itemid=143`?

Comment: I turned it into an answer below. If it helped you please put that as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make sure your redirect outputs to

```
localhost/webapp/admin.php?check=C7&itemid=143
```

Notice the `&` this makes sure you can use `check` and `itemid` as a variable.
Also make sure to use the lowercase as Rasmus mentioned.

The variable at the moment looks like this (Output of `$_GET` array)

```
Array ( [check] => C7/itemid=143 )
```

See that it's all saved in `check`?

Answer (score 1):

That's because of lowercase / uppercase. and missing ;
try:

```
$_GET['itemid'];
```